# What is the difference between \(...) and \(raw: ...) when creating syntax nodes for Swift Macros?

Tags: swift, string-interpolation, swift-macro

Consider this macro that generates an extra `Int` property as a peer, prefixed with `_`, just as an example:

```
public enum SomeMacro: PeerMacro {
    public static func expansion(of node: AttributeSyntax, providingPeersOf declaration: some DeclSyntaxProtocol, in context: some MacroExpansionContext) throws -> [DeclSyntax] {
        guard let binding = declaration.as(VariableDeclSyntax.self)?.bindings.first else {
            return []
        }
        
        return ["var _\(raw: binding.pattern) = 0"]
    }
}
```

In the examples in the Swift Syntax repository (such as [`CaseDetection`](https://github.com/apple/swift-syntax/blob/main/Examples/Sources/MacroExamples/Implementation/Member/CaseDetectionMacro.swift)), and is also what I did above, `\(raw: ...)` was used to interpolate the old name to form the name of the new member.

From looking at the documentation for [`SyntaxStringInterpolation`](https://swiftpackageindex.com/apple/swift-syntax/509.0.0/documentation/swiftsyntaxbuilder/syntaxstringinterpolation), I found that there is also an [`appendInterpolation` overload](https://swiftpackageindex.com/apple/swift-syntax/509.0.0/documentation/swiftsyntaxbuilder/syntaxstringinterpolation/appendinterpolation(_:)-xeck) with no parameter labels, and takes anything that conforms to `SyntaxProtocol`. i.e. I can do:

```
return ["var _\(binding.pattern) = 0"]
```

This produces the same expansion in this case.

What is the difference between these two overloads of `appendInterpolation`? When should I use each one? The documentation for `SyntaxStringInterpolation` doesn't say. Is there a situation where they would expand to substantially different code?

Of course, I understand that one can put *anything* in`\(raw: ...)` - I'm only comparing the situation where one is interpolating syntax nodes.

---

Side note: I also found [another overload](https://swiftpackageindex.com/apple/swift-syntax/509.0.0/documentation/swiftsyntaxbuilder/syntaxstringinterpolation/appendinterpolation(_:format:)) that takes a `SyntaxProtocol` and a `format:` parameter, so perhaps the difference between `\(...)` and `\(raw: ...)` is only whether formatting is performed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around in the SwiftSyntax source code, I found the two `appendInterpolation`s are implemented quite differently ([source](https://github.com/apple/swift-syntax/blob/main/Sources/SwiftSyntaxBuilder/Syntax%2BStringInterpolation.swift#L72)):

> ```
> public mutating func appendInterpolation<Node: SyntaxProtocol>(
>   _ node: Node
> ) {
>   let startIndex = sourceText.count
>   let indentedNode: Node
>   if let lastIndentation {
>     indentedNode = Indenter.indent(node, indentation: lastIndentation)
>   } else {
>     indentedNode = node
>   }
>   sourceText.append(contentsOf: indentedNode.syntaxTextBytes)
>   interpolatedSyntaxNodes.append(
>     .init(
>       node: Syntax(indentedNode),
>       startIndex: startIndex,
>       endIndex: sourceText.count
>     )
>   )
>   self.lastIndentation = nil
> }
>
> public mutating func appendInterpolation<T>(raw value: T) {
>   sourceText.append(contentsOf: String(describing: value).utf8)
>   self.lastIndentation = nil
> }
> ```

Clearly, the `SyntaxProtocol` overload is "smarter". It applies indentation to the code in the given syntax node, and also adds the node to the `interpolatedSyntaxNodes` array. The `raw:` overload only converts `T` to `String`, then appends it to `sourceText`.

Then I tried to figure out how `interpolatedSyntaxNodes` is used. For that, I went to [`init(stringInterpolation:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift-syntax/blob/main/Sources/SwiftSyntaxBuilder/SyntaxParsable%2BExpressibleByStringInterpolation.swift#L67):

> ```
> public init(stringInterpolation: SyntaxStringInterpolation) {
>   self = stringInterpolation.sourceText.withUnsafeBufferPointer { buffer in
>     var parser = Parser(buffer)
>     // FIXME: When the parser supports incremental parsing, put the
>     // interpolatedSyntaxNodes in so we don't have to parse them again.
>     let result = Self.parse(from: &parser)
>     return result
>   }
>   if self.hasError {
>     self.logStringInterpolationParsingError()
>   }
> }
> ```

At the time of writing, it seems like `interpolatedSyntaxNodes` is *not used at all*. Whichever overload I use, `sourceText` gets appended with the new code, and then parsed by `init(stringInterpolation:)`.

The FIXME comment suggests that in the future, the things in `interpolatedSyntaxNodes` won't be parsed again.

From this, I think it is quite safe to assume that `\(...)` is designed to be used when you want to add the syntax node *itself* to the AST, *not* when you just want to interpolate the textual content of that node. In cases like `"var _\(binding.pattern) = 0"`, we don't want the node `binding.pattern` itself in the AST - we want to form a new pattern node with `_` and the textual content of `binding.pattern`.

That said, I'm not sure what the parser will do to `"var _\(binding.pattern) = 0"`, once incremental parsing is supported, but it is *possible* that it might fail to parse it.

---

To summarise, use `\(...)` when you want to put the node itself into the AST, so that it doesn't have to be parsed again, e.g.

```
"var x = \(expr)" // where expr is an ExprSyntax
```

Use `\(raw:...)` when you want to interpolate the textual content of a node to form new nodes, such as when forming new names, or referring to newly formed names.